# WebService application - return new objects from static/shared method

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Would using a static/shared method in a webservice application thread safe? This method would be called heavily to retrieve new instances.

For instance:

```
 Public Shared GetPerson(ByVal name as String,ByVal surname) as Person
    Dim p As New Person
    p.Name = name
    p.Surname = surname
    p.Addresses = GetAllAddresses(name)
    return p
End Function
```

**UPDATE 1**

The code posted is just a quickly typed up sample for the purpose of the question. GetAllAdrresses would return a new instance of another type so it would be thread safe.

My concern is  that if many requests are made at the same time I'm not returning a person instance with the name of one request and surname of another.

Comment: That depends, what does the code for GetAllAddresses look like?

Answer (score 1):

It will only be thread-safe if `GetAllAddresses` is thread-safe.  Otherwise, it's fine.

Regarding your **UPDATE 1**, yes, that will work fine.  It will never get confused as you described.  It's always creating new instances of objects, so there is no chance that the various threads will interfere with each other's data.

Answer (score 1):

Given that GetAllAddresses only performs read actions, then the static method is entirely thread safe as each re-entering thread will create its own Person instance, the reference to which will be stored on the stack.

So, regarding UPDATE 1, because each thread is working with a new Person instance, there is no way that two different threads could write to the same person instance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you try to make a `new Person` and return it to your page.

By that code the thread safe have no actually meaning. What you should look, is the moment you going to save that person back on the database, there you must make it thread safe to avoid to write it multiple times.

There are two ways to make it safe when you going to write it back on the database (create new, or make update)

One is to use mutex, and the second is to use the standard asp.net session that is lock the page, and its going to make thread safe the full process.